# VBA - Column indexing stops working

Tags: excel, vba

I have a strange case where column indexing stops working all of a sudden.

If I do the following to retrieve a cell value, it works:

```
MsgBox (Range("AB1").Cells.Value)
```

However when I try the following, it does not:

```
MsgBox (.Cells(1, 28).Value)
```

All the cells up until the 28th column work, but after than it starts returning blank values. Shouldn't the two pieces of code reflect the same output though?

Comment: Is there a reason you have **Range().Cells.Value** instead of **Range().Value**? Also, gotta ask, what value is in AB1?

Comment: Just habit. Regardless, it gets the correct value, where the second piece code (which I'd like to use) does not. The value of AB1 is a text value that I'd like to retrieve.

Comment: Just to clarify, **.Cells(1, 27).Value** works as expected?

Comment: Yes, it gets the column header beforehand, as expected. But the next column (i, 28) returns a blank value.

Comment: `Range` is referencing the active sheet, `.Cells` is referencing a `With` block, which may or may not also be the active sheet.  So you might be looking at two different sheets

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @chris neilsen for his handy comment.

I had a hidden worksheet that was getting picked up before the active sheet, because they were named similarly. One had the columns I was looking for, the other did not.